# Route from Laravel to a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, routes, laravel-5.1, shared-hosting

I'm trying to access the Rails Admin Engine from a Laravel application.

But everytime I try to access it I get `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php` which is expected since I did not route it in the Laravel app.

I have created a symbolic link (because I'm using a Shared Host, so I can only work with symlinks and the .htaccess file) inside the Laravel application called `rails`
I can use it and access the public folder of the rails application, with no problem.

But if I use /rails/admin it breaks again with the `NotFoundHttpException`

Here is my routes.rb: (I really don't know much about rails)

```
Rails::Application.routes.draw do
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
root :to => redirect("rails/admin") ==> here I already tried some other codes but none worked
```

Current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(rails)

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution!

Just had to add an .htaccess inside public folder of the RoR application with this line:

```
RewriteEngine off
```